# In which case, echo can append the NULL characters unexpectedly

Tags: linux, shell, echo, mmap, brk

I'm working on a mini machine(MEM: 256M), its OS is linux.

I wrote a bash script, which would be executed while the system is booting (executing command is added into `/etc/rc.local`).

In this script, there is a command `echo "a_long_string" >> /etc/custom_config`.

`a_long_string` is a string, whose length is 248.

To test the script, I rebooted the system many times and I found an issue:

Sometimes, the command `echo "a_long_string" >> /etc/custom_config` will append 248 NULL characters plus the `a_long_string`, which means that, normally after executing this command, we could find the `a_long_string` at the end of the file `/etc/custom_config`, but sometimes I do find that the appended string becomes as below:

```
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@...a_long_string
```

I'm trying to figure out what happened. Does `echo` a long string may cause some issue like this on a small RAM system?

Comment: You tagged this question as `bash`. Is it really `bash` or something like a busybox shell? If working with strictly POSIX shells, I would generally recommend `printf` over `echo`, as it's generally more portable, but I doubt that's the source of your current issue. Try using `set -x` and outputting stderr to log file to debug.

Comment: @jordanm  It's standard POSIX shell. However, the main memory is very small and the hard disk is a SD card.